# Why am I not getting the minimum value in an array JAVA?

Tags: java, arrays, min

```
import java.util.*;
public static void main(String[] args) {
    
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter the size ??");
    int n = sc.nextInt();
    int[] marks = new int[n + 1];
    
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        System.out.println("Enter " + i + " number ??");
        marks[i] = sc.nextInt();
    }
    
    System.out.println("The  following numbers are : ");
    for (int j = 0; j < marks.length - 1; j++) {
        System.out.println(marks[j] + " ");
    }
    
    int max = marks[0];
    int min = marks[0];
    int s = marks.length;
    for (int i = 0; i < s; i++) {
        if (marks[i] > max) {
            max = marks[i];
        }
        if (marks[i] < min) {
            min = marks[i];
        }
    }
    
    System.out.println("Max is " + max + " Min is " + min);
}
```

Output:

```
Enter the size ??2
Enter 0 number ??
56
Enter 1 number ??
56
The  following numbers are : 
56 
56 
Max is 56 Min is 0
```

Comment: Because you have `int[] marks = new int[n+1];`. It should be only `new int[n];`. `+1` adds an extra 0 at the end of the array, and you are not filling that slot with user input. So if the user always enters numbers greater than zero, that last element will be the min.

Comment: You create an array one bigger than you need. Last item is always `0`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Next time, febore you jump into the internet for help, please try this approach. It will solve your problem much quicker.

```
for (int i = 0; i < s; i++) {
    System.out.println("DEBUG: number in index " + i + " is " + marks[i]);

    if (marks[i] > max) {
        System.out.println("DEBUG: number is greater than current max " + max);

        max = marks[i];
    }
    if (marks[i] < min) {
        System.out.println("DEBUG: number is smaller than current min " + min);

        min = marks[i];
    }
}
```

This process is called "debugging". It can be done by adding spurious amount of logging like above or by stepping through the code with a debugger.

Answer (score 0):

The size of mark array is 3 in the above example

```
 int[] marks = new int[n + 1];
```

Let total number of marks is (n) : 2

We are creating the array with size of 3.

By default value for int primitives in java is 0

marks array is created with size 3

```
{56, 56, 0}
```

As per the logic the minimum value among these three elements are 0